# What are all of the known passwords to Gryffindor Tower?

Tags: harry-potter

In every book, there is a new password to the Tower, with it usually being changed at least once over the course of the book.

**What are all of the known passwords to Gryffindor Tower?**

Comment: I'm not sure why this is being downvoted, given that there are a finite number of HP books.

Comment: @MrLister possibly due to it being a self-answered question. Lots of people on here do not take kindly to people who self-answer questions which they already know the answer to, purely for rep!

Comment: @TheGiantofLannister And a self-answered question with no real basis (why it's being asked) even less.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Harry Potter and the Philosopher's/Sorcerer's Stone

- **Caput Draconis** - Chapter 7
- **Pig snout** - Chapter 9

### Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets

- **Wattlebird** - Chapter 5

### Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban

- **Fortuna Major** - Chapter 5
- **Scurvy cur** - Chapter 11
- **Oddsbodikins** - Chapter 12
- **Flibbertigibbet** - Chapter 15

### Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire

- **Balderdash** - Chapter 12
- **Fairy lights** - Chapter 22

### Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix

- **Mimbulus mimbletonia** - Chapter 11

### Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince

- **Dilligrout** - Chapter 12
- **Tapeworm** - Chapter 23

Answer (score 11):

There are a few other passwords to Gryffindor Tower not mentioned in [the other answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/121580/100430):

### Goblet of Fire

- **Banana Fritters**

> This time it was Ron who waited outside to give the Fat Lady the
>   password ("banana fritters").

### Half-Blood Prince

- **Baubles**

> “Baubles,” said Harry to the Fat Fady, this being the new, festive
>   password.

- **Abstinence**

> “I’ve got something for you, Harry,” said Hermione, neither looking at
>   Ron  nor giving any sign that she had heard him. “Oh, hang on —
>   password. Abstinence.”

- **Quid Agis**

> "*Quid agis*?" he said tentatively to the Fat Lady, wondering what he
>   would find inside.